# импорт пакета в GO

Tags: golang, импорт

Я импортирую библиотеку raylib, у меня ошибка:`could not import github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib (no required module provides package "github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib")`

```go
package main

import rl "github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib"

func main() {
    rl.InitWindow(800, 450, "raylib [core] example - basic window")
    defer rl.CloseWindow()
    rl.SetTargetFPS(60)

    for !rl.WindowShouldClose() {
        rl.BeginDrawing()

        rl.ClearBackground(rl.RayWhite)
        rl.DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, rl.LightGray)

        rl.EndDrawing()
    }
}
```

команда  `go get -a` не помогла
код взят [отсюда](https://github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go), но у меня в vsc не работает

Answer (score 1):

Выполните в терминале команду `go mod tidy`. Эта команда выкачает все необходимые модули, запишет их версии в `go.mod`, а хэши исходников в `go.sum`

```
$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib
go: downloading github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib v0.0.0-20230928181314-dc2584151090
go: downloading github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go v4.5.0+incompatible
go: found github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib in github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib v0.0.0-20230928181314-dc2584151090
```

После завершения команды VS Code некоторое время потупит, но в конце концов найдёт в кэше Go необходимый модуль, и перестанет ругаться.